# Why i can use function name in pascal as variable name without definition?

Tags: freepascal

I was wondered about very strange behaviour in free pascal functions, [described in docs](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Functions).

It is said, that following code will be compiled/executed successfully:

```
function Test : integer;
begin
  Test := 2;
end;

begin
  WriteLn(Test());
end.
```

But if i use function name `Test` in the right side of equation, it will perform recursive loop.

So, pascal functions, from one side, define variable with their name `Test` and type of function return value `integer`. From other side, you can still call function (make recursive call using its name).

Why?! What is the goal?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. Why wouldn't you be able to do recursion. It's the developer's responsibility to check their code makes sense and can complete correctly

Comment: @DavidBrossard totally agreed about recursion - it is supported in most popular programming languages. I am confused about auto-defined variable with function name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside function's body there is special variable with name identical to the function name. It used to keep function result.

It was introduced in the original Pascal syntax. Later to prevent inconveniences another variable named `Result` was introduced and it is just alliance to the previous one:

```
Test := 2;
i := Result + 3; // Here i = 5;
```

So, for now, `Test := 2;` and `Result := 2;` is same.

In case of usage of function name at the right side of equation, it is interpreted as variable, not as function calls:

```
Test := Test + 1; // Increments Test value
```

but you still can to call function recursively using brackets:

```
Test := Test() + 1; // Recursion
```

So, you have three ways to return value from the function (for your example):

```
function Test : integer;
begin
    Test := 2; // Function result = 2
    Result := 2; // Same to previous
    Exit(2); // Sets function result to 2 end exits immediately
end;
```

It is up to you which method to use.

Comment: Wow! Awesome answer. Thank you!