# Not overloading operator

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Good day, I'm doing some Codeforces exercises in my free time, and I had a problem to test if the user was a boy or a girl, well, my problem isn't that, i have just demonstrated the code.
While compiling my code in my computer ( I'm using  version 3.0.4 for i386 ) i get no error, but codeforces gives me this error

```
program.pas(15,16) Error: Operator is not overloaded: "freq(Char;AnsiString):LongInt;" + "ShortInt"
program.pas(46,4) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
```

The error wasn't clear enough to me, as the same script was perfectly compiled with my version.
The platform is using ( version 3.0.2 i386-Win32 ).

```
program A236;
uses wincrt, sysutils;

var
    username : String;


function freq(char: char; username : String): Integer;
var 
   i: Integer;
begin
    freq:= 0;
    for i:= 1 to length(username) do
        if char = username[i] then
            freq:= freq + 1;
            //writeln(freq);        
end; 

function OddUserName(username : String): Boolean;
var
    i, counter: Integer;

begin
    OddUserName:= false; // even
    counter:= 0;
    for i:= 1 to length(username) do 
        if freq(username[i], username) <> 1 then    
            delete(username, i, 1)
        else
            counter:= counter + 1;  
    if counter mod 2 <> 0 then
        OddUserName:= true; // odd
    //writeln(counter); 
    //writeln(OddUserName);                 
end;        

begin
    readln(username);
    if not OddUserName(username) then 
        writeln('CHAT WITH HER!')
    else 
        writeln('IGNORE HIM!'); 


    //readkey();    
end.
```

The error is supposed to be at this line probably  :

```
function freq(character: char; username : String): Integer;
```

Thanks for everyone who helps.

Comment: Not sure about the compiler error (maybe its related to the `char` parameter being named the same as a data type, try renaming it) , but you do have a logic bug. You can't modify a string while you are iterating through it. The `length` is not reevaluated on every loop iteration, it is evaluated only once and cached. But even if it were reevaluated, the loop would skip a character after each `delete`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I fully understand you If I enter `aaaaa` the loop will still go up 6 doesn't matter if I deleted a char, while, if I reevaluate the length it will still skip the first char in this case. I'll try a better algorithm, thank you very much for this important point you've mentioned.

Comment: The error is on line 15 which is "freq:= freq + 1;" You are using the function name on the right of the assignation. It is probably not correct. Try using a local variable instead of freq and at the end, assign freq with the local variable. I'm just guessing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that, but I also think you cannot use it on the right of assignation. At that place, it is considered as a function call and requires arguments. "Result" can be used, not the function name. But it seems the user don't use Delphi and "Result" pseudo variable may not exists in that dialect. That's why I suggested to use a local variable.

Comment: @fpiette Actually it worked, thanks, I didn't know that I can't assign a value directly to the function name in the process, do you have any explanation why it's not correct?

Comment: @fpiette "*I also think you cannot use it on the right of assignation*" - modern Pascal compilers do allow that.  So this is either a bug in the failing compiler, or the compiler is just really old and doesn't allow it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau D10.4.1 doesn't want it.

Comment: Remy: or people selected an old TP compatible mode, and since there are no $Mode directives, it probably is default mode, which is TP dialect based. Since FPC can compile both Indy and ICS, it shouldn't be hard to infer that it CAN support the result variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of a function, the function's name can be used as a substitute for using an explicit local variable or `Result`. `freq()` and `OddUserName()` are both doing that, but only `freq()` is using the function name as an operand on the right-hand side of an assignment.  `freq := freq + 1;` *should* be a legal statement in modern Pascal compilers, see [Why i can use function name in pascal as variable name without definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979207/).

However, it would seem the error message is suggesting that the failing compiler is treating `freq` in the statement `freg + 1` as a function type and not as a local variable. That would explain why it is complaining about not being able to add a `ShortInt` with a function type.

So, you will have to use an explicit local variable instead, (or the special `Result` variable, if your compiler provides that), eg:

```pascal
function freq(charToFind: char; username : String): Integer;
var 
  i, f: Integer;
begin
  f := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(username) do
    if charToFind = username[i] then
      f := f + 1;
      //writeln(f);
  freq := f;
end;
```

```pascal
function freq(charToFind: char; username : String): Integer;
var 
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(username) do
    if charToFind = username[i] then
      Result := Result + 1;
      //writeln(f);
end;
```

Comment: this is probably the most convincing answer, in the old version it's only possible to assign a local variable with the same type to the function name but not a value, it seems that in the new generation of Pascal compilers it's legalized. Unfortunately, my compiler doesn't provide the Result variable, but a local variable worked well. Thank you very much!